# Nmap port scanning array

Tags: arrays, bash, nmap

I am doing a nmap bash script, and I am just wondering if there is any possibility to use array list for my port commands. For example:

```
port=[23,45,75,65]
for i in 21 do

nmap -p x,y 192.168.1.$i

done
```

e.g. At the `x,y` place I want to use the number `23,45`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if that's what you want, but you can try this:

```
ports="23,45,75,65"

for i in 21 do
    nmap -p "$ports" 192.168.1.$i
done
```

You can also do:

```
ports="23,45,75,65"
targets="1-25"
nmap -p "$ports" "192.168.1.$targets"
```

Comment: at the last place can i do this ? $i-$y

Answer (score 0):

Scanning an array of ports is already built in to nmap.  See http://nmap.org/book/man-port-specification.html for more details on the syntax, but here's an excerpt that may give you what you need:

```
For example, the argument -p U:53,111,137,T:21-25,80,139,8080 would scan UDP ports 53, 111,and 137, as well as the listed TCP ports.
```